# Next.js React Server Component - re-render only RSC component(s)

Tags: next.js, react-server-components

I'm using Next.js and I would like to be able to re-render only RSC components without refreshing whole page (like `router.refresh()` does) as it's loosing current page state.

I want to call refresh in "strange" places like on mutation succeess (from react-query) or in forms, not directyl related to refreshed component itself.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

I've tried `router.refresh()`, but I'm loosing page state (for example table pagination, table is refetching data,...).

Comment: Looking for the same answer. Its weird how NextJs server actions are in production and yet we can do these simple things?